log transform left data in r
I am having trouble finding the transformation operation for left/negatively  skewed data. The catch? All of my values are between 0 and 1. As such, trying the standard log10 transformation command computes a bunch of NAs.
log10(max(df$Var+1) - df$Var)

What do you recommend?
I computed the skewness at  -0.6818167
Thank you

Log transforms will not tend to make left skewed data less skew, but more; nor is it always useful with right skew distributions (sometimes it does hardly anything, sometimes it leaves you with more left skew than the right skew you might have had). However, often people are transforming variables needlessly, even counterproductively. What are you doing that would lead you to need to make this variable less skew? What does the variable measure?

Can a subset of your data be shared AND how the data was generated AND your objective?  If all values are between 0 and 1 (and none of the values are 0 or 1), then depending on how the data was generated, you might try log(df$Var/(1-df$Var)).  But maybe a better approach is to not transform and if simply describing your data is the objective then maybe use a nonparametric density estimate (using density or a function described in https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/density-estimation.pdf).

Your question actually begs a more important question...why are you transforming this variable in the first place? Is this for a regresson? If so, please specify how your variables in your regression are being used. This will allow others to provide a better answer for you, as transformation may not even be necessary depending on your use-case.

If you must use a logarithm, then apply it to the right skewed dataset obtained by subtracting each value from 1.  But, as the preceding comments suggest, that's just a bandaid.  We would prefer to understand your underlying statistical problem so we can give more useful advice.

Here's the deal. My variable of interest is a proxy measure of poverty in a dataset of 1000s of districts. I measure poverty as the % of the population with access to sewage, electricity, and running water. Results range from 0 to 100% but tend to cluster around 90%. As such, the distribution is left skewed.

Ok, I tried a new tactic. I used a squared transformation. It worked well. Skewness is now down to -0.08323571. My question is as follows. This variable--poverty--is just a control in my regression model. I don't care that much in laying down the interpretation. Do you think this is an appropriate course of action? THank you
